# OpenTK Windows Application screen size?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, opengl, opentk

I'm working on a small project in OpenTK and I want to get the screen resolution of the primary monitor. My application is a windows application, I have tried to use
 
`width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;`

But The name 'screen' does not exists in the current context.
I have included the required using statements, is there any other way to get screen size?

Comment: Did you add a reference to `System.Windows.Forms`? That's where `Screen` is defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `DisplayDevice`.

```
 int width = DisplayDevice.Default.Width;
 int height = DisplayDevice.Default.Height;
```

[Source here](https://github.com/opentk/opentk/blob/d50c2fcea0696d3cc82aeb339e15c049405129ba/src/OpenTK/DisplayDevice.cs#L116)